# how to capture whole layout when layout exceeds screensize in android

Tags: android, android-layout

In my application i am zooming my layout when i zoom my layout i want to capture my layout.I tried below code but it is capturing only the content which is visible in screen.please help me how to capture layout.

```
       View content = findViewById(R.id.main_container);
    content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
    // actual width of the image (img is a Bitmap object)
    // int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    // int height = bitmap.getHeight();

    // recreate the new Bitmap and set it back

        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(
                l1.getWidth() * 2, l1.getHeight() * 2,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888));


    // Bitmap mb = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    Canvas bitmapCanvas = new Canvas();
    bitmapCanvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
    bitmapCanvas.scale(2.0f, 2.0f);
    content.draw(bitmapCanvas);
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);

    File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            "saved_images");
    imagesFolder.mkdirs();
    String fileName = "final-" + String.valueOf(n) + ".jpg";
    File output = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);
    while (output.exists()) {
        n++;
        fileName = "final-" + String.valueOf(n) + ".jpg";
        output = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);
    }
    Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(output);
    OutputStream imageFileOS;
    try {
        imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriSavedImage);
        imageFileOS.write(out.toByteArray());
        imageFileOS.flush();
        imageFileOS.close();




    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Maybe you should use ``View.draw`` method instead of drawing cache?

Comment: can you give me code for functionality

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way for grabbing the screenshot of a layout. I'm writing this out of my head so the code may contain some errors (can't verify it right now);

```
ViewGroup bg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.your_layout_id);
Bitmap screenshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(vg.getWidth(), vg.getHeight(),
                                        Bitmap.Config.RGBA8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(screenshot);
vg.draw(c);
```

Now I'm not sure whether this works any better but should draw something at least according to the documentation.

Comment: hi i tried your code it is also take layout which is visible on screen but not the whole screen